# AWS ELB using SSL shows request time out

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, timeout

I'm trying to use SSL on apache2 with Digicert's certificate.
I'm able to upload my certificates on a single server(EC2 Instance) editing my conf file in sites-available. But when I try to connect SSL using ELB, it shows nothing but 408 Request Timeout.

Here's my conf file.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    Alias /media/ blahblah
    <Directory blahblah >
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory blahblah >
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    DocumentRoot blahblah
    WSGIScriptAlias / blahblah

    <Location "/css">
        SetHandler None
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

If I add VirtualHost *:443 below and redirect 80 to 443, SSL works in a single server. But that makes 503 Service Unavailable error if I use ELB. Of course I uploaded certificates in Load Balancer Listeners(443), and used Route53 to connect ELB to my domain. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: please edit your question and add a screenshot of the 'listeners' tab on your ELB.

Comment: here's the image. https://tagme.to/test/screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The easy way**

You can terminate your SSL on your ELB if you installed the cert there.
Then from the ELB listener 443->80 on your internal server.
Once that works I would adjust the security policy on the web server to only accept port 80 from your load balancer

**Otherwise** you need to install the same cert on ELB and your server.
ELB listner 443->443 .  Make sure that you have your certs configured in your :443 virtual host in Apache.

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP

        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/star.example.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/star.example.com.key

        ServerName      "one.example.com"
        DocumentRoot    "/var/www/html/one"

        CustomLog       "/var/log/httpd/one-access.log" combined
        ErrorLog        "/var/log/httpd/one-error.log"

        <Directory /var/www/html>
                AllowOverride none

                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory> </VirtualHost>
```